# Confusing naming convention for Environment.SpecialFolder

Tags: c#, .net, io

I found that on a 64 bits system:

```
   Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.SystemX86);
```

Returns actually `%windir%/SysWow64` and :

```
   Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System);
```

returns  `%windir%/system32`

Why did they use this confusing naming convention ?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is compatibility. See [this article](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/32-64-bit-windows-folder-x86-syswow64.htm).

> This may seem a bit illogical if you look at the folder names, but
>   there is an explanation to this. **It has to do with compatibility.** Many
>   developers have hard coded the path to the system folder in their
>   applications source code. They have included "System32" in the folder
>   path. And to preserve compatibility, if the application is converted
>   to 64-bit code, the 64-bit system folder is still named System32.
>
> But what about 32-bit applications that have the system path hard
>   coded and is running in a 64-bit Windows? How can they find the new
>   SysWOW64 folder without changes in the program code, you might think.
>   The answer is that **the emulator redirects calls to System32 folder to
>   the SysWOW64 folder transparently** so even if the folder is hard coded
>   to the System32 folder (like C:\Windows\System32), the emulator will
>   make sure that the SysWOW64 folder is used instead.